# $A$ closed subset of metric space. Then there exists a continuous function $f:A \to [0,1] \subset \mathbb R$ with $f^{-1}(0)=A$.

Tags: general-topology, limits, analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $A$ is a **closed** non-empty subset of a metrix space $(X,d)$. We define the distance from $x\in X$ to the set $A$ as:
$$ d(x,A):= \inf_{a\in A} d(x,a).$$
The problem I then solved is that it turns out that $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ **is continuous**. We derive some estimates using the triangle inequality and the property of the infimum being the greatest lower bound. We then show with the usual $\epsilon-\delta$ that whenever $x \to x_0$ we get  $f(x)\to f(x_0)$ for any $x_0 \in X$.

Now the exercises I am working on suggest that this problem can be used to tackle the following:

> There exists a continuous function $f:X \to [0,1] \subset \mathbb R$ with $f^{-1}(0)=A$.

Now I know that continuity implies sequential continuity and that closed sets contain all their limit points. This means that for $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ a sequence in $A$ with $x_n \to x$ we know $x \in X$, and also such a function $f$ has the property that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. I am not entirely sure how the pieces fit together.

Comment: Define $f : A \rightarrow [0,1]$ by $f(x)=0$ for every $x \in A$.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that, it almost seemed too easy... why does it matter that $A$ is closed in this sense right? - there was a typo, $f$ needed to be defined on all of $X$.

Comment: I guess the question is incorrect, and you should rather define $f : X \rightarrow [0,1]$ continuous such that $f^{-1}(0)=A$. That would be correct and that would use the fact that $A$ is closed.

Comment: Yeah I realised that too after a second. It did not seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define$$f(x)=\frac{d(x,A)}{1+d(x,A)}.$$Then $f$ is continuous, $f$ is a map from $X$ into $[0,1]$ and $f^{-1}(0)=A$ (since $A$ is closed; in general, $f^{-1}(0)=\overline A$).

Comment: Easier than I thought, thanks again José.

Comment: You could also do $f(x) = min(1, d(x,A))$.